# android, canvas undo last stroke

Tags: java, android, canvas, bitmap, draw

What's the simplest way to do an Undo last stroke from canvas? Just undo once is ok, two or three is a plus although I'd want to avoid using Stack and 'push' in favor of ArrayList since I had a working method with , push and pop but seems like that messes up the drawing speed for some reason. So now I just want a simpler less undo levels without Stack. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are u using drawBitmap to draw on screen?
If yes then u r storing the bitmaps into sd card. Then just delete the last one and show the previous one.

Comment: Yes using drawBitmap. I want to do it in memory no writing to file. i think i did something before but i was getting crashes due to memory issue, i was using ArrayList<Bitmap> so i guess i need more specific code example of proper implementation.